# Split comma separated entries to new rows using Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have this data in a sheet

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | angry birds, gaming | Youtube, twitch | Google,Facebook |
| 2 | nirvana,rock,band | Music, world,Entertaiment | Twitter,Instagram, snapchat |

What I want to do is split the comma separated entries in the second column and insert in new rows like below:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | angry birds | youtube | google |
| 1 | gaming | Twitch | Facebook |
| 2 | nirvana | Music | Twitter |
| 2 | rock | World | Instagram |
| 2 | band | Entertainment | Snapchat |

I already have a formula can anyone correct this for col A and B Can any one help me with Col C and col D

```
    Option Explicit

Const ANALYSIS_ROW As String = "B"
Const DATA_START_ROW As Long = 1

Sub ReplicateData()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iSplit() As String
    Dim iIndex As Long
    Dim iSize As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End With

    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ANALYSIS_ROW).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    For iRow = lastrow To DATA_START_ROW Step -1
        iSplit = Split(ws.Cells(iRow, ANALYSIS_ROW).Value2, ",")
        iSize = UBound(iSplit) - LBound(iSplit) + 1
        If iSize = 1 Then GoTo Continue

        ws.Rows(iRow).Copy
        ws.Rows(iRow).Resize(iSize - 1).Insert
        For iIndex = LBound(iSplit) To UBound(iSplit)
            ws.Cells(iRow, ANALYSIS_ROW).Offset(iIndex).Value2 = iSplit(iIndex)
        Next iIndex
Continue:
    Next iRow

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably better to do this with Get & Transform (also known as Power Query).

Comment: We are happy to help you if you can provide any code you've already tried and ask specific questions on the problems you encounter.

Comment: many many nearly exact questions are on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003866/excel-macro-split-comma-separated-entries-to-new-rows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560718/split-comma-separated-entries-to-new-rows

Comment: ^^^^^ Seems not coincidental that your sample data in column B matches these questions.

Comment: Seems to me that this is a homework assignment given the similarities to the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a start, i don;'t have much time to formulate a proper answer, this takes A1:A3 and puts in one word per cell.

```
Dim arrIn() As Variant
Dim strJoined As String
Dim arrOut() As String

arrIn = Application.Transpose(Range("a1:a3"))
strJoined = Join(arrIn, ",")
arrOut = Split(strJoined, ",")

Range("b1").Resize(UBound(arrOut) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrOut)
```

[image]